# Changing number of points extracted on a linestring using `raster::extract` in R

Tags: raster, r, extract

I am trying to use a linestring to extract values from a raster using `raster::extract`. In the example below, I can only extract 123 points. Is there a way to extract more or less points without changing the line. I can't seem to find an argument that does this.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
x=c(5, 95)
y=c(20, 50)
line = SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(cbind(x,y)), ID="a")))


ext <- raster::extract(r, line)[[1]]
nrow(ext)
# [1] 123
```

Comment: When I run your code I get `ext` as a vector, not a data frame or matrix, so I see `nrow(ext)` as `NULL`. Its *length* is 123 though - its a vector of 123 values: `[1] 247 130 144 136 244 255 ....`. Probably a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The 123 returned values are the 123 cells that the line crosses. If you sample points on the line using `spsample` you can extract at those point locations:

```
pts500 = spsample(line,500,type="regular")
plot(r)
plot(pts500,add=TRUE)
extract(r, pts500)
#  [1] 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 252 252 252 252 252 255 255
# [19] 255 255 255 255 254 254 254 254 254 254 254 254 254 254 254 207 207 207
```

[image]

Note that if you sample 123 points on the line you probably won't get the same extraction as extracting the line directly because it only extracts cells at each point, whereas extract with a line gets any cells the line even slightly nicks, which might not have one of the 123 points in it.